# Vampirates: is there any information on Lorcan's "crossing story"?

Tags: character-development, vampirates

Over the course of Justin Somper's *Vampirates* series, Grace gathers a lot of "crossing stories" (stories of a person's death and subsequent revival as a vampire) from Vampirates including Sidorio, Darcy Flotsam, and Johnny Desperado. She keeps them all in a little notebook that she takes with her wherever she goes, the *Nocturne* or Sanctuary or elsewhere.

One "crossing story" I can't remember seeing is that of Lorcan Furey, the Vampirate who rescued Grace from the ocean at the very beginning and later becomes her boyfriend. The fact that she doesn't know his story is mentioned once or twice in the series, and I'm pretty sure we still haven't heard it properly by the end of the last book. But I also seem to remember reading an interview with the author, Justin Somper, in which he's asked about Lorcan's "crossing story".

**What do we know canonically about Lorcan's backstory?** Any information from the 6 books, or from interviews with the author or further publications, would be welcome (but no fanfictions!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Not yet, but the author plans to write about it.

In an interview included in the final book *Immortal War* (published in 2011), Somper said:

> *Will we ever find out Lorcan's "Crossing Story"?*
>
> Yes! I promise you will. I have fresh thoughts about this.

More recently (2013), he commented [on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/OfficialJustinSomperPage/posts/10151898278890609?comment_id=306480820&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R%22%7D) saying:

> I do know Lorcan's Crossing Story and I definitely plan to write it in the future. I'd love to write about Lola again too. You're right that we know some key facts about her background, but she's llkely to have kept back a few secrets, don't you think? It would be fun to drop in on Grace and Lorcan too. Watch this space!

Answer (score 2):

Lorcan does mention to Grace, after the subject of his crossing comes up in what I believe was *Blood Captain*  he says

> Someday I will tell you about Cathal, and the whole wretched story

after Grace has an  encounter with a bloodlusting Johnny. From this we can tell Lorcan has a brother, most likely older, that has some role in how he died and maybe even how he crossed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, and thanks for this answer! But where did you get the idea of a *brother* specifically? Is there some surrounding context to the quote, or could this Cathal equally well be a friend or a cousin or an enemy or something else?